# Splitting arraylist into seperate arrays with every 3rd element being the 1st element of the next

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, split, edges

I am trying to split arraylists into seperate arrays in order to obtain "edges". I need to split the arraylist into arrays of size 3 with the 3rd element of the newly split-created array being the 1st element of the next. What i have currently done is that the arraylist is successfully split into arrays of 3 although the 3rd element is not the 1st element of the next.

Example: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] would need to be split up as [1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7] but what i am getting is [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7]

This is the code i used:

```
for(ArrayList<String> path : allPaths) {
    edges = separate(path, 3);
}
for(List<String> edge : edges){
    System.out.println("Edge: "+edge);
}
```

Then this method is accessed

```
static <T> List<List<T>> separate (List<T> path, final int size){
    List<List<T>> separated = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < path.size(); i+= size){
        separated.add(new ArrayList<>(path.subList(i, Math.min(path.size(), i + size))));
    }
    return separated;
}
```

Comment: Did you already try to replace `i += size` with `i += size - 1` in the loop?

Comment: I just tried that and it works, although i am getting an extra final array being created with the last element as the first element. Example: [1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7],[7]

Comment: How would i be able to fix that pls?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Isn't that the same solution? Just adding a -1?

Comment: I will accept it, but how would i add another exception if the final created split array just contains 1 element? (The last element of the previous array). As that would not be needed

Comment: I would appreciate it if people wouldn't argue. @ArvindKumarAvinash can you please help me out with my previously asked question? As i do not know how to do it, i tried doing 

if(separated.size() == 1){
                separated.get(i).clear();
            }

but it didnt work

Comment: @MrMosby - Sure. Where is that question?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash This was the question: How would i add another exception to remove the final array if the final created split array just contains 1 element? (The last element of the previous array). As that would not be needed

Comment: @MrMosby - I've updated my answer to fulfil this requirement. Please let me know in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks

Comment: @MrMosby - What if the split array just contains 2 elements? Should that be added? If not, check the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
        System.out.println(separate(list, 3));
    }

    static <T> List<List<T>> separate(List<T> path, final int size) {
        List<List<T>> separated = new ArrayList<>();
        List<T> temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i += size - 1) {
            temp = (List<T>) path.subList(i, Math.min(path.size(), i + size));
            if (temp.size() != 1) {
                separated.add(new ArrayList<T>(temp));
            }
        }
        return separated;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9]]
```

## Update

@Mr Mosby - You posted the comment about the additional requirement of not adding the sublist to `separated` if it has just one element and accordingly I updated my answer given above. Just in case your requirement is, not to add the sublist to `separated` when it has less number of elements than `size`, given below is the solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        System.out.println(separate(list, 3));
    }

    static <T> List<List<T>> separate(List<T> path, final int size) {
        List<List<T>> separated = new ArrayList<>();
        List<T> temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < path.size(); i += size - 1) {
            temp = (List<T>) path.subList(i, Math.min(path.size(), i + size));
            if (temp.size() == size) {
                separated.add(new ArrayList<T>(temp));
            }
        }
        return separated;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]]
```